# How can i show all the list of my with parameters using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my function code to show all the list of my code of discipline but i cant view my code of discipline because of data:{params}
always

> alert('Could not get data');

please help

*Below is my ajax function :*

```
function showallcod() {
  var company_id = $('#company_id').val();
  var location_id = location;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '<?php echo base_url()?>app/code_of_discipline/showallcod',
    data: {
      "company_id": company_id,
      "location_id": location_id
    },
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(datas) {
      var html = '';
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr>' +
          '<td>' + datas[i].numbering + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + datas[i].title + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + datas[i].description + '</td>' +
          '<td>' +
          '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>' +
          '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>' +
          '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
      }
      $('#showdata').html(html);

    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Could not get data');
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: may be because of type in ajax change it to get or post

Comment: i do that but its not working i add method: 'GET'
but still same result

Comment: if i remove the where clause in my model i get all the list but only i want is have a filtering

Comment: thank you for your reply i get the solution of my problem thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Your js function should be like this :*

```
function showallcod()
{
    var company_id = $('#company_id').val();
    var location_id = location;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', /* or GET */
        url: "<?php echo base_url('app/code_of_discipline/showallcod')?>",
        data:{"company_id": company_id , "location_id": location_id},
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(datas){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<datas.length; i++)
            {
              html +='<tr>'+'<td>'+datas[i].numbering+'</td>'+'<td>'+datas[i].title+'</td>'+'<td>'+datas[i].description+'</td>'+'<td>'+'<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>'+'<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>'+'</td>'+'</tr>';
            }
            $('#showdata').html(html);

        },
        error: function(){
          alert('Could not get data');
        }
    });
 }
```

*Since you `set dataType: 'json'` in your ajax your method should return data in json format*

Your `showallcod` method should return data with `json_encode`();

```
public function showallcod()
{
    $data = 'whatever data may be string or array';
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: what ever you returning from your method should be encoded in json format

Comment: the solution is change the type: 'GET'
thankyou pradeep